# How to test if Office Dev PnP (powershell) is working on my dev environment?

Tags: powershell, development-enviroment, pnp

I am using SP2013 onpremises on my development environment. I am updating my SharePoint at this moment because I was on SP1. Someone told me I was using an to old version to use Office Dev PnP. I

would like to test if Office Dev PnP is working after the updates. Does someone know some easy small Office Dev Pnp Powershell commando where I can verify if it is working?

I have 0,0 experience with the Office Dev Pnp.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Powershell commands:

First generate an XML template from one of your sites (preferably the root site of a site collection). Make sure it contains some custom lists and libraries.

```
Connect-SPOnline -Url http://yourlocalserver/yoursite
Get-SPOProvisioningTemplate "C:\temp\template.xml"
```

Then Apply the generated templated to another empty site that you created before manually:

```
Apply-SPOProvisioningTemplate -path "C:\temp\template.xml"
```

Now check if the custom lists and libraries are available in the second site.